# Install winget by the command line (powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, winget

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to setup windows dev machines. I want to use winget but I don't see any easy way just to install winget using the commandline. You have to either use the windows store or download the msxibundle from github.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/download/v1.3.2691/Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle -OutFile .\MicrosoftDesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle
```

Both of these require user's interaction instead of just running the script and walking away. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: It's the installer, provided by the vendor that must allow options for silent installs, not PowerShell or other scripting languages. Languages are just used to start the installer and you pass the proper switches/install parameters. [What did you search for regarding ```msxibundle``` installer features](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27winget+msxibundle++silent%27&t=h_&ia=web)?

Comment: @postanote I couldn't find anything using google. Start-Automating answer works great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After having downloaded your msixbundle into `.\MicrosoftDesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle`, you can install it using Windows PowerShell (not PowerShell Core), there's a command to help: `Add-AppXPackage`:

```
Add-AppXPackage -Path .\MicrosoftDesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle
```

Should allow you to install the package you downloaded.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

I devised a somewhat different approach, which installs the latest version:

```
# get latest download url
$URL = "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/latest"
$URL = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL).Content | ConvertFrom-Json |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty "assets" |
        Where-Object "browser_download_url" -Match '.msixbundle' |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty "browser_download_url"

# download
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -OutFile "Setup.msix" -UseBasicParsing

# install
Add-AppxPackage -Path "Setup.msix"

# delete file
Remove-Item "Setup.msix"
```

Comment: This seems to rely on Internet Explorer's infrastructure for request handling. Returns an error if IE is not initialized or missing. Adding `-UseBasicParsing` to `Invoke-WebRequest` makes it work. There's a nice progress bar in the console as a bonus.

Comment: I wrote up a fixed command with other error cases at https://winget.pro/winget-install-powershell/.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a script for that directly from Microsoft. Script can also be used to install winget into Windows sandbox.

[Original page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/#install-winget)

```
$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'
$latestWingetMsixBundleUri = $(Invoke-RestMethod https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/latest).assets.browser_download_url | Where-Object {$_.EndsWith(".msixbundle")}
$latestWingetMsixBundle = $latestWingetMsixBundleUri.Split("/")[-1]
Write-Information "Downloading winget to artifacts directory..."
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $latestWingetMsixBundleUri -OutFile "./$latestWingetMsixBundle"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx -OutFile Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
Add-AppxPackage $latestWingetMsixBundle
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.WinGet.Client
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome! This is an interesting response, can you provide a description of what it does? Far as I can tell, it automatically installs [NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget), then prompts to install an untrusted repository called `PSGallery`. I didn't end up with winget in my path after trying it.

Comment: @Siegfried Hi, on my system, this command needed the admin rights so I used an admin account to run it. I ended up having winget inside the `$env:localappdata/Microsoft/WindowsApps/` of the non-admin user directory.

Comment: The [`Microsoft.WinGet.Client`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.WinGet.Client) PowerShell module does _not_ contain [`winget.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/), the [Windows Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/) CLI.
Instead, the module is meant to be a PowerShell-friendly _alternative_ to `winget.exe`, based on _cmdlets_ such as `Install-WinGetPackage`.
Caveat: As of v1.6.3133.0 of this module and PowerShell (Core) 7.4.0, the module is _broken_, and I am unclear on its maintenance status.

Comment: Powershell 7 only.

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that the code linked above and provided by Microsoft is not accurate. Updated with correct PowerShell:

```
$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'
$latestWingetMsixBundleUri = $( Invoke-RestMethod https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/latest ).assets.browser_download_url | Where-Object { $_.EndsWith( ".msixbundle" ) }
$latestWingetMsixBundle = $latestWingetMsixBundleUri.Split("/")[-1]
Write-Information "Downloading winget to artifacts directory..."
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $latestWingetMsixBundleUri -OutFile "./$latestWingetMsixBundle" 
Add-AppxPackage $latestWingetMsixBundle
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me

```
# get latest download url
$URL = "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/latest"
$URL = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL).Content | ConvertFrom-Json |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty "assets" |
        Where-Object "browser_download_url" -Match '.msixbundle' |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty "browser_download_url"
$LicenseFileURL = 'https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/download/v1.2.10271/b0a0692da1034339b76dce1c298a1e42_License1.xml'

# download
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -OutFile "Setup.msix" -UseBasicParsing
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $LicenseFileURL -OutFile  'license.xml' 

# install
#Add-AppxPackage -Path "Setup.msix" -LicensePath .\license.xml
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -PackagePath "Setup.msix" -LicensePath 'license.xml' -online 

# delete file
Remove-Item "Setup.msix"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not work anymore as you need to install pre-req libraries like Xaml 2.7, https://github.com/asheroto/winget-install/releases this works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

It's a per user appxpackage.  This worked for me from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/#install-winget.  You have to pipe 'y' to it the first time to accept the eula (or there's an --accept-source-agreements parameter).  Winget seems pretty dopey.  The powershell module is only for powershell 7.

```
invoke-command computer01 { 
  Add-AppxPackage -RegisterByFamilyName -MainPackage Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe
  echo y | winget list
}
```

From reddit, get the fullname of winget.exe under "C:\Program Files\Windowsapps":

```
$winget = Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller -allusers | 
  % InstallLocation | dir -filter winget.exe | % FullName | select -last 1

& $winget list --accept-source-agreements
```

Answer (score 0):

To install winget for the current user, download the PreIndexed package that contains the local copy of the database for the community repository from here:

```
https://cdn.winget.microsoft.com/cache/source.msix
```

then in PS run:

```
C:\path\to\downloaded\file Add-AppXPackage source.msix
```

If you want to install winget for all users, run this PS script:

```
$localFolderPath = "C:\temp"
$localPackage = "C:\path\to\downloaded\file\source.msix"
DISM.EXE /Online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackagePath:$localPackage /SkipLicense
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft [suggest the following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/#install-winget):

```
Add-AppxPackage -RegisterByFamilyName -MainPackage Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

After running this, the `winget` command appears.
However, I had an additional issue with the following error when trying to run `winget upgrade --all`:

```
Failed when opening source(s); try the 'source reset' command if the problem persists.
```

To fix this, I had to run the following, as suggested in the [winget discussions page on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/discussions/3258#discussioncomment-5939793):

```
Add-AppxPackage -Path https://cdn.winget.microsoft.com/cache/source.msix
```