# Cannot install winget as normal user from powershell : winget is not installed in $env:localappdata/microsoft/WindowsApps/

Tags: powershell, nuget, winget

Trying to install winget as a non-admin user from powershell.

Here is what I did :

I first installed NuGet (because Winget said it needs it) :

```
PS D:\Users\test> Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Scope CurrentUser                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         The package(s) come(s) from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'https://onegetcdn.azureedge.net/providers/nuget-2.8.5.208.package.swidtag'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
nuget                          2.8.5.208        https://onege... NuGet provider for the OneGet meta-package manager


PS D:\Users\test>
```

Than I installed winget :

```
PS D:\Users\test> Install-Module -Name Microsoft.WinGet.Client -Scope CurrentUser

Untrusted repository
You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its InstallationPolicy value by running the
Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the modules from 'PSGallery'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y
PS D:\Users\test>
```

But the $env:localappdata/microsoft/WindowsApps/ directory is not even there and therefore Winget is not installed into it :

```
PS D:\Users\test> winget -v
winget : The term 'winget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ winget -v
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (winget:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS D:\Users\test> ls $env:localappdata/microsoft/WindowsApps/
ls : Cannot find path 'D:\Users\test\AppData\Local\microsoft\WindowsApps\' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ ls $env:localappdata/microsoft/WindowsApps/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Users\test.m...ft\WindowsApps\:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS D:\Users\test>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The **[`Microsoft.WinGet.Client`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.WinGet.Client)** module **does *not* contain [`winget.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/)**, the [Windows Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/) CLI.

  - It is meant to be a PowerShell-friendly *alternative* to `winget.exe`, providing *cmdlets*, such as `Install-WinGetPackage`.
  - **Caveat**: As of v1.6.3133.0 of this module and PowerShell (Core) 7.4.0, the module is *broken*, and I am unclear on its maintenance status.
  - Generally, PowerShell [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) do *not* ship with *executables*, and their installation locations are known to PowerShell only, and are unrelated to the lookup mechanism used by the system for executables via the `PATH` environment variables.
- **`winget.exe` *should be preinstalled*** on Windows 11 and recent versions of Windows 10.

  - On older versions / machines where `winget.exe` was removed you may be able to **(re-)install it on demand**:

    - *Interactively*: via the **Microsoft Store**, where it comes with the **[App Installer](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NBLGGH4NNS1)** package.
    - *Programmatically*: via the **instructions** provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/#install-winget-on-windows-sandbox).

      - Note: These instructions are for Windows Sandbox environments, but should work in general.
      - They include installation of dependencies as well, which may or may not be necessary on a given machine.
      - They use [`Add-AppxPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage) to install the package for the *current* user only. If you want to install for *all* users, use [`Add-AppxProvisionedPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/add-appxprovisionedpackage) instead (requires *elevation*; use with `-Online`).
  - For a given user, `winget.exe` should (then) be available via the `"$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps"` directory, which should be an entry in the `PATH` environment variable (`$env:PATH`). Verify its availability and version number by running `winget.exe --version`

Comment: `winget` is not installed (or somehow removed) on my system, that is why I'm trying to install it from CLI. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76822206/5649639) that I could install `winget` by installing the `Microsoft.WinGet.Client` powershell module.

Comment: @SebMa, the answer you link to is flawed (I've left a comment there). Other answers there do show how to programmatically install `winget.exe`, in addition to the _interactive_ method that was already part of my answer. However, I've amended the answer to summarize _programmatic_ installation options.

Comment: Users can run the "Repair-WinGetPackageManager" cmdlet in the Microsoft.WinGet.Client PowerShell module to repair/install WinGet. I'd use -Force and -Latest to force the install for the latest stable release.